# Can you create a type from nested object values inTypescript

Tags: typescript

If we have an object like

```
const Colors = {

    Orange: {
        Light: "#230498",
        Dark: "#867583",
    },

    Blue: {
        Light: "#768493",
        Dark: "#039583",
    },
}
```

Can you create a type from the Color object that restricts parameters like so

```
function setColor(color: SomeType){
    ....
}

// Allowed
setColor(Colors.Orange.Light);
setColor(Colors.Blue.Dark);

// Not Allowed
setColor('#ffffff');
setCOlor(SomeOtherObject.Color.Blue.Dark);
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine someone can write something more concise than me. I would suggest declaring the Colors object 'as const', but there are other ways, the important bit is not to allow TS to widen the type of Colors.

```
const Colors = {
    Orange: {
        Light: "#230498",
        Dark: "#867583",
        Blur: "ffff"
    },

    Blue: {
        Light: "#768493",
        Dark: "#039583"
    },
    Jam: {
        Blur: "df"
    }
} as const;

const SomeOtherObject = {
    Color: { Blue: { Dark: "#039583" } }
} as const;

type C = typeof Colors;

// courtesy of https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31192
type ObjKeyof<T> = T extends object ? keyof T : never;
type KeyofKeyof<T> = ObjKeyof<T> | { [K in keyof T]: ObjKeyof<T[K]> }[keyof T];
type StripNever<T> = Pick<T, { [K in keyof T]: [T[K]] extends [never] ? never : K }[keyof T]>;
type Lookup<T, K> = T extends any ? (K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never) : never;
type SimpleFlatten<T> = T extends object
    ? StripNever<
        {
            [K in KeyofKeyof<T>]:
                | Exclude<K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never, object>
                | { [P in keyof T]: Lookup<T[P], K> }[keyof T];
        }
    >
    : T;

type A = SimpleFlatten<C>;

type AllowedCols = A[keyof A];

function setColor(color: AllowedCols) {}

setColor(Colors.Orange.Dark);

// This has to be allowed, it's just the nature of TS
setColor(SomeOtherObject.Color.Blue.Dark);

// not allowed
setColor("#fffff");
```

Edit - What I was writing before was trash, haven't done any typescript in a while..., luckily our man jcalz comes to save the day

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31192

Answer (score 1):

For this use case I don't believe a generic flatten is necessary. Similar to Countingstuff's answer you'll need to declare the color objects with `as const` to prevent the rgb-value types from widening to `string`, but then the code below should do the job. ([link to TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2BhA9gG0QJ2AXmAJRgY3QBMAeAZzDQEsA7AcwBpgLr6A%20AWAChRxo4ACgENkMMGDjY8hNKRa1GCFOk49QkWEtRocdAEYl4wGAA8JNImS0qsCANoBrGBEQAzBAF1uvDYJFiJXQMBYzMYCythUXEYNlskbSCSAG87AGlgWmAnF3cBDwAuax19EgF0jzYAX1VvUEIaCmBCbStsZLredCF6GCKOtV4QZCo6AAswIoAiAGIAJgBmAAYAFgBOAA4phk6hoiE0B2mZjYA2AHYAVg2Fqd2QKp3B0D1kAFc%204AGh0BHxyeAs3Opw261uTx%20IH2h2OSwWa2u4PuoAAbjA0BAACIHI6AmZLAkEgCMd2eD12VWAQisDQo3F2tLAzEQAFsYAB5MBjdHsvQAKwITPayJa6H6wFeH3F0NxszhCJu22Afwmx1cMHVrlcU2AlKqFKpNMQjTA9OevmAADURFQiEFbFEAjAkr43M1lGgyHEAPTeq02u36WyzRarTY6gA%20eLOV0VwCjQJBYMjePliJTcsJSxJZt4rjeNHwYCoxuYYgS6AAFKK0EVrSNA3oAJRffVcXa%204AAQWQqAA7jAiLsyOWPdWPWQAHTdXqTlVgJsAbmHo%20049ak8lMEnMqXK7AFbQlbIrI5XJ5-MFk5rm-e293i%20AnZE-cHTHwPRoiCZejgQhRiC2oOhqpvC6aZFYQjACiAbAGgQZZAABjWZCIZOuagJ2ABy37dr2iADkOzwjgeY6zFqFHanuxGrlWJ5spy3JoLyApFteHq3h8c6jBM1FAA))

```
type Color = Record<string, string>
type Palette = Record<string, Color>
type ColorRgb<C extends Color> = C[keyof C]
type PaletteRgb<P extends Palette> = ColorRgb<{[K in keyof P]: ColorRgb<P[K]>}>

const colors = {
  orange: {
    light: "#230498",
    dark: "#867583"
  },
  blue: {
    light: "#768493",
    dark: "#039583",
    veryDark: "#000001"
  }
} as const

const someOtherObject = {
  color: { blue: { dark: "#039583", light: "#fefeff" } }
} as const

type ValidRgb = PaletteRgb<typeof colors> // ValidRgb = "#230498" | "#867583" | "#768493" | "#039583" | "#000001"

function setColor(color: ValidRgb) {}

// Allowed
setColor(colors.orange.light);
setColor(colors.blue.dark);
setColor(someOtherObject.color.blue.dark); // allowed, cannot be avoided as "#039583" is a valid rgb in `colors`.

// Not Allowed
setColor("#ffffff");
setColor(someOtherObject.color.blue.light);
```

Comment: Better, I prefer this answer. I would go with this OP.

Comment: Thank you! I upvoted yours for the insight regarding keys that aren't shared between all colors.